# jQuery add text to same textarea multiple times glitch

Tags: jquery, html, textarea, append

I built this reply system where people can reply to other comments by clicking `reply`. When they click it, it runs this function in order to put `@user` at the beginning of their comment:

```
$('#inputField').focus();
$('#inputField').text('');
$('#inputField').append(atowner);
```

The `atowner` is a variable passed through when calling the function.

This works pretty well because you can keep clicking `reply` to many different comments and it will always erase and refill the `<textarea>` with the new `@newuser`.

My problem is that if I type something in the `<textarea>`, then erase it all, THEN click to reply, it doesn't work. But it's funny because the actual HTML still shows that it put `@user` into the `<textarea>` but you can't see it on the site. And when you go ahead and submit the comment, it is submitted without the `@user`.

So basically, why is the HTML lying to me and why isn't it showing up only when I type-and-erase in the `<textarea>` first (works rest of the time)?

Comment: What is in `atowner` - simple text, html, anything else?

Comment: @Andrei `atowner` is always a variation of "@" and a username (string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an input (even thought it's a `textarea` you should be using `val()` not `append` or `text` so your code would be:

```
$('#inputField').focus();
$('#inputField').val(atowner);
```

And this should solve your problem, you should also use `val` to retrive the contents as well.

This works when the page loads and when before the user performs any action because it reads the DOM to populate the visible `textarea` but is then treated as an input after the user begins to use it as such which is why it no longer renders anything from the DOM inside.

Comment: This works. I had to use `val` and I took away the `html('')` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
$('#inputField').focus().val(atowner);
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you use

```
$('#inputField').val(atowner);
```

?